# Create drop down menu from unordered list where first item appears separate

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I can only change the CSS, not the HTML. Solving with Javascript or Bootstrap is not an option. Given this constraint, is it possible to create a drop down style navigation menu from an unordered list where one of the list items is separated from the rest of the group?

What I currently have is a drop down menu that looks like this:

[image]

What I would like to be able to do using only CSS is modify the navigation bar to separate the Login link. It would look like this:

[image]

Here is the code snippet I am working on:

```css
.menu-bar {
    background: black;
    padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown button {
    background: #FF6223;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em 0.8em;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none; 
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.2em 0.8em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    color: #333333;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
    background: #BBBBBB;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-bar">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button>Navigate</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a solution.

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/bellu/j4e5L7y0/1/) the complete Fiddle.

```
    .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    /*display:none;*/
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none; 
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li{
    display:none;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu li{
    display:block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu li:first-child:hover ~ li{
    display:none;
}


.dropdown a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.2em 0.8em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    color: #333333;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
    background: #BBBBBB;
}

.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu li:first-child{
    display:block !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    top: -27px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: white;   

 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Bellu. This looks good from a glance. Once I get these changes integrated into another website, I'll mark an answer for this question.

Comment: @ThisClark Ok, don't care i will wait.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
.menu-bar {
    background: black;
    padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown button {
    background: #FF6223;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em 0.8em;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none; 
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu li:not(:first-child) a {
    position: static;
}
.dropdown a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.2em 0.8em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    color: #333333;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
    background: #BBBBBB;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li:first-child {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li:first-child a {
    position: static;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0.4em 0.8em;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Comment: That's very close. Is it possible to have Login remain visible while the others are collapsed under navigation? I tried visibility: visible to no success.

Comment: @ThisClark give that a try!

Comment: This is looking promising. When I mouseover Login, the navigation menu drops down. I'm looking at how to prevent that. Once solved, it's case closed! Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.menu-bar {
    background: black;
    padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown button, .loginBtn {
    background: #FF6223;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em 0.8em;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none; 
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.2em 0.8em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    color: #333333;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
    background: #BBBBBB;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-bar">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button>Navigate</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">                
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown"> 
       <a class="loginBtn" href="#login">Login</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't change the underlying HTML like that